# Update Schema with Doctrine without dropping every table?

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm writing a small web app for a website, and for that have to access a few already existing tables on the database. Those I will not add or change anything to.

I will also create some new tables of my own, where I will write stuff obviously.

Now the issue:

- When I'm running the updateSchema, it deletes every table in the DB that I have not specifically made an entity for. There are like 30 tables in there, and I need only 2! I don't want to touch the others at all. It shouldn't delete them.
- Of those two, I really only need 3 columns "id", "name" and "email", but the tables have again like 10 columns that I'm not interested in at all and therefore didn't map to my Entity object. The update did delete every column that I hadn't matched. Again, it shouldn't touch these at all..

I'm not quite sure how to fix the issue, so it won't just rewrite the entire database.

This is the setup.php I'm using to update the schema:

```
<?php

require_once '../inc/config.inc.php';

$em= Inc\Config::getEm();

$schemaTool = new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\SchemaTool($em);

$metadata = $em->getMetadataFactory()->getAllMetadata();


try {
    $schemaTool->updateSchema($metadata);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'WARNING: There was a problem updating the database schema: ';
    echo $e->getMessage() . '<br />';
    if (preg_match("/Unknown database '(.*)'/", $e->getMessage(), $matches)) {
        die(
                sprintf('Create the database %s with the Collation utf8_general_ci', matches[1])
        );
    }
}

echo 'Setup successfully completed!';
```

Comment: Have you considered [generating entities from the existing schema](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)?

Answer (score 0):

According to Doctrine's docs(1):

```
void updateSchema(array $classes, boolean $saveMode = false)
```

> Updates the database schema of the given classes by comparing the
>   ClassMetadata instances to the current database schema that is
>   inspected.
>
> boolean   $saveMode   If TRUE, only performs a partial update without dropping assets which are scheduled for deletion.

To avoid dropping assets outside the given metadata, you should pass true as the saveMode parameter value.

(1) https://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.6/Doctrine/ORM/Tools/SchemaTool.html#method_updateSchema